# how can i change slider and form height according to screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to show a form on a slider on medium and a large size screen it's working fine but on a small screen  and extra small i am posting a screen shot
i want this
on extra-small screen my what to do go automatically downward as form height increase 
but in this case they are overlapping

[this is a small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRYXN.png)

[this is extra small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm3Iq.png)

```css
        #slider{
            width:auto;
            padding:0px;
        }
   
        #form {
            width: 920px;
            height:100%;
        }
         .panel{
             background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
             box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 20px 20px 20px;
            }
```

```html
<div id="slider" >

        <div id="jssor_1"style="height:100%;width:100px;position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; ">
       
             <!-- Loading Screen -->
       <div class="">
       <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        </div>
        
       <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
            
            <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="images/madina.png" />
            </div>
            <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="images/jeddah.png" />
            </div>
            <div data-p="225.00" data-po="80% 55%" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="images/accra.png" />
            </div>
            <a data-u="any" href="http://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">Full Width Slider</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form"   class="container">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:5px;">
        <div class=" col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
         <div class="panel panel-default" style="border-color:green" >
          <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:white" >
             <h2 class="panel-title" style="color:forestgreen" >Search & Book <span class="glyphicon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane"></i></span></h2>
       </div>
       <div class="panel-body">
         <form role="form" runat="server" class="">
          <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:0px">
           <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-10" style="margin-left:20px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                                        <label style="font-size:13px;margin-left:5px">Name</label>
                                <input  id="n" name="n" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Name" required="required" value="" runat="server"/>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-10" style="margin-left:20px">
            <div class="form-group">
                                        <label style="font-size:13px;margin-left:5px">Email</label>
             <input id="em" type="text" name="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="email" value="" runat="server"/>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row" style="margin-top:0px">
          <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-10" style="margin-left:20px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                                        <label style="font-size:13px;margin-left:5px">Phone Number</label>
             <input type="text" name="password" id="tel" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Phone Number" runat="server" />
            </div>
           </div>......
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want `height: 100vh`. Vh is relative to 1% of the height of the viewport, so it will fill the entire screen.

For more information about CSS units, you can go to w3schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: on extra small screen form overlapping the lower div